# Firefox activeElement not working in jQuery submit()

Tags: jquery, firefox

Note: this code snippet doesn't work in Chrome (Javascript log says: "Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.")

Instead see:
https://jsfiddle.net/dr5e5qdr/

Basically in browsers such as Chrome, document.activeElement.name is working within a jQuery submit()... but in Firefox 50.1 for Mac it isn't working. (it says "undefined")

```js
$(function(){
 $('#test-form').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    alert('activeElement name: '+document.activeElement.name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test-form">
  <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Button 1" />
  <input type="submit" name="button2" value="Button 2" />
  <button name="button3">Button 3</button>
</form>
```

Is there some way of detecting the clicked button that works in all browsers?

Comment: well I'm getting that message in console but in Chrome. Works fine in FF50.1

Comment: its worked in firefox...

Comment: it says "undefined" for me in firefox rather than "button1" etc

Comment: Just listen for the click on the buttons instead

Comment: @adeneo that won't catch submissions using enter from a text field. Luke,  use `this.querySelector()` where this is the form itself and you pass in the selector.

Comment: @JuanMendes - Then there's no button to get. This is just clientside, as on the server it would be easy to check for the clicked buttons name in the formdata.

Comment: @adeneo I see... the OP wants to know which button was clicked from the client side, I didn't realize there were multiple buttons, I thought the first two inputs were text fields. As a small improvement, OP could use a single click handler on the form and use `event.target`